# How can I fix the error AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'swifter'?

Tags: python, pandas, swifter

This is pretty direct, I was trying to replicate the example used in Swifter page https://github.com/jmcarpenter2/swifter. However, I keep getting the error AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'swifter'. What's up with that?

Update - The example I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import swifter 

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'y': [5, 6, 7, 8]})

# runs on single core
df['x2'] = df['x'].apply(lambda x: x**2)
# runs on multiple cores
df['x2'] = df['x'].swifter.apply(lambda x: x**2)

# use swifter apply on whole dataframe
df['agg'] = df.swifter.apply(lambda x: x.sum() - x.min())

# use swifter apply on specific columns
df['outCol'] = df[['inCol1', 'inCol2']].swifter.apply(my_func)
df['outCol'] = df[['inCol1', 'inCol2', 'inCol3']].swifter.apply(my_func,
         positional_arg, keyword_arg=keyword_argval)
```

Comment: Please provide the entire error output, as well as a [mcve].

Comment: @DumbML what version do you have? Try updating to the latest verison.

Comment: @amc the example is exactly what you see in the link I posted. Just the same, there is just one small script there with df.swifter.apply() and it was the one I used

Comment: @DavidErickson I thought I had the last version because I just installed

Comment: did you download 'status.csv' and 'trip.csv'. Are these files in your current directory?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and solved it like this:

```
from swifter import swifter
```